# Refreshing LinkedIn Access Tokens

Tags: refresh, linkedin-api, token, access-token

I am attempting to refresh a LinkedIn user's access token given their current access token. This is the documentation that I am following: http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token

The steps I follow:

1. Make a POST request to the requestToken endpoint (https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken)
2. Make a POST request to the authenticate endpoint passing the request token as a parameter.

After this the response should be a newly refresh access token but I am receiving a 302 response instead.

Comment: 302 is a redirect status.  What happens if you follow the redirect?

Comment: It sends me to a link with the LinkedIn authentication box. I sign in and it gives me a 5 digit code and says to exchange that in the app. I want to have the refresh done automatically without any user interference.